# html2canvas - capture embedded video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I am trying to integrate [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) in my web application as a way to share content to facebook. The div I want to capture contains an iframe with embedded youtube video:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $data['video'] ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is my facebook button:

```
<a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" onclick="shareToFb()">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

And my JS:

```
function shareToFb() {

    html2canvas($('#mydiv'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            canvas.toDataURL('<?= base_url() ?>assets/images/sharing/');
        }
     });

   }
```

Clicking on the button rises this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.frames.gm-master.initWidget is not a function

My guess is that capturing iframe is not supported. Please, advise.

Comment: You cannot 'capture' cross domain iframe content

Comment: Is there any alternative that supports this ?

Comment: None i know. You could restream video from your own server to get it available on same domain but that's against youtube TOS, so...  Maybe youtube API offers some methods to take screenshot but i don't know youtube API. Maybe searchfor it in the doc. But still be aware that canvas itself is restricted to same domain origin

Comment: I have performed some tests and seems like this error has nothing to do with the iframe.